# How to add labels to the end of a highcharts line graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm replicating this chart http://www.texasheartinstitute.org/HIC/Topics/images/growth_chart_girl_web.gif I'm trying to add the name of the series to the end of the line like they have with the percentages.

I've searched but can't really find much on the subject. Essentially I'm looking to have a label for the series to be put at the end of the graph.

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the [dataLabel](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.dataLabels) for the last point:

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    align: 'left',
    x: 3,
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    overflow: true,
    crop: false,
    format: '{series.name}'
}
```

See this fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/f6f53/).